# Present alert after dismissing View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I'm using the newest `Xcode` and `Swift` version.

I'm presenting a specific `View Controller` like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let contactViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "contactViewController")
show(contactViewController, sender: self)
```

I'm dismissing this `View Controller` like this:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I want to present an `UIAlertController` right after dismissing the `View Controller`.

This:

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Your message was sent", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
let alertButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
alertMessage.addAction(alertButton)
self.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

… of course doesn't work because I cannot present an `UIAlertController` on a dismissed `View Controller`.

What's the best way to present this `UIAlertController` after the `View Controller` is dismissed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in completion handler by getting top controller like this

```
self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            let alertMessage = UIAlertController(title: "Your message was sent", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
               let alertButton = UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default)
               alertMessage.addAction(alertButton)
            UIApplication.getTopMostViewController()?.present(alertMessage, animated: true, completion: nil)
        })
```

Using this **extension**

```
extension UIApplication {

    class func getTopMostViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
        if var topController = keyWindow?.rootViewController {
            while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
                topController = presentedViewController
            }
            return topController
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First see `while let`, it is really off my book. Does this while loop will terminate when `let presentedViewController` is nil ( aka. topController has no presentedViewController).

Answer (score 0):

Use Jawad Ali's extension, we could anchor the current presented ViewController.

And if you want to dismiss that alert later, you could do it in another completion handler as below code showed. In my case, I save a song to one playlist and dismiss this playlist and show a short time alert to let user know that saving ok.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self?.removeSpinner()
    self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Save to playlist", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        UIApplication.getTopMostViewController()?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false) { _ in
                alert.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
        })
    })
}
```